# Mapping Kernel-level Threads, User-level Threads to Process/Threads

Tags: kernel, process, thread

I know this question has been brought up many times, however I can't find anywhere a definitive answer, so here it goes again:

Is it true that Kernel Level Thread has it's own unique PID, while the User Level Threads share only one (parent's) PID?

Comment: Is this a general question, or a question in relation to a specific Unix?

Comment: I'd like to hear a UNIX specific answer and then a general one. I just try to understand how exactly the stack looks like (not call stack, just the levels or execution aka "user-code", "user-thread", "process", "system call", "user-level threads", "kernel-level threads", "CPUs"). Ideally I'd love to see the picture with all those components